# Poisson Distribution?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

There exists 1000 boxes. These boxes are randomly filled with balls. How many balls are required in order that only 1 in 100 boxes are left empty?

This sounds like a Poisson distribution problem to me unless I am mistaken.

Where the formula for Poisson Distribution is:

$$Pr(x, y) = \frac{\lambda^{x}e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$$

I deduced that $Pr(x, y) = \frac{1}{100}$ since I have a $\frac{1}{100}$ chance of choosing the selection. I also used $\lambda = 1000$ since I have 10 boxes. Where I try to find the value $x$.

However, [the answer I got is a decimal below 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/100=%28%28a%5Ex%29%28e%5E-a%29%29/x!%20where%20a%20=%201000%20what%20is%20x). Obviously not right.

---

My other attempt is to use the Poison Distribution formula for an expected value. Using the same variable predictions as above.
$E|X-\lambda| = 2exp(-\lambda)\frac{\lambda\lfloor\lambda\rfloor+1}{\lfloor\lambda\rfloor!}$

However, [x came out to be 1000 this time](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100%2aabs%28x-1000%29%20=%202%2aexp%28-1000%29%28%282000%2b1%29/1000!%29). Which I doubt as well.

---

Am I using the right approach?

To be quite honest, it seems to me that the problem is missing some information on how the balls are chosen, but I am reassured otherwise. Help is appreciated.

Comment: There may be some missing requirement. It is possible, though highly unlikely, that if we assign $100000$ balls at random, they will all end up in the third bin. The problem may ask for the smallest number of balls such that with probability *at least* 0.95$, *at most* $1$ bin will remain empty.

Comment: I'm glad that I am not the only one who thinks that this is a poorly designed question. Especially from someone with a lot of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The question is well formulated, i think. 
It may be formulated more specifically:

We are placing balls randomly into $n=1000$ boxes and continue the procedure of placing balls until $m=10$ boxes remain empty.

Thus the number $r$ of balls is not fixed in advance but is just a random size. We are interested in expected value of $r$ which we denote by $E[r]$

Now, let us remember a classic problem:

$r$ balls is randomly filled in $n$ boxes. Find the probability of finding exactly $m$ boxes empty.

We need an asymptotic expression of this probability:

$$P(\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^{m}e^{-\lambda}}{m!}$$

where

$\lambda=ne^{-\frac{r}{n} } ;n\rightarrow \infty $

of which $r(\lambda)=n\ln\frac{n}{\lambda}$

Finally, using the results above we get:

$$E[r]=\int_0^{\infty}r(\lambda)P(\lambda)dx=4556$$

(for $m=10$ and $n=1000)$

Unfortunately, the integral has no closed form solution.

To get the standard deviation of $r$

$$\delta_r =\sqrt {E[r^2]-E^2[r]}$$

we need to compute
$$E[r^2]=\int_0^{\infty}r^2(\lambda)P(\lambda)dx$$

Result: $\delta_r \approx 300$